# What is the right notion of equivariant Cech cohomology?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, equivariant, cohomology

What is the right definition of equivariant Cech cohomology is so that given a $G$-space $X$, $H^1_G(X;H)$ classifies $G$-equivariant principal $H$-bundles on $X$?

Comment: H is abelian, right?  If H is not abelian, you will fail to construct the long exact sequence past the first cohomology group (cf. Giraud's Cohomologie non-abelienne).  

Comment: At this point, it really makes most sense to define the cohomology of the orbifold X/G. That orbifold is best encoded by the *groupoid* whose objects are *X* and whose arrows are XxG. In that way, you avoid the possibility of doing various non-sensical constructions (such as keeping track of different G-space structures on H - no offence).

Comment: What is a $G$-equivariant principal $H$-bundle?

Comment: Andre is right to point out that the way I first went at it doesn't make sense. There's some extra data that I need to encode in the definition of cochains in order to capture that a G-equivariant principal H-bundle E has isomorphisms $g:E_x\rightarrow E_{gx}$ for any $g\in G$ and $x\in X$ and I′d confused this data with a notion of $G$−action on $H$. 

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: You say: right definition but usually that requires a meaning for 'right'. For example, working with $G$-spaces the whole time look at what a group object in that category looks like, here you may need to replace $G$-spaces by spaces over $BG$. Now look what torsor / principal bundle objects over a G-space in that category would be and so on.  That is very general and may be way too general for what you want but is one interpretation.  André's Orbifold approach (and orbifold cohomology à lå Moerdijk and Pronk?) may answer your query by interpreting things differently.

Comment: I forgot the paper by Moore and Segal who look at Turaev's HQFTs in a bit this way. (see http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0609042)

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for commenting on this.  I should have clarified that I want an answer which works for (compact) lie groups, not just for finite groups.  The approach I'm currently most comfortable with involves defining a pre-topology on the category of smooth G-manifolds by saying that a cover $\mathscr{U}\rightarrow X$ is a G-equivariant smooth submersion.  Then I can define the Cech complex as the limit over all covers of the mapping simplicial set whose source is the coherent nerve of the translation category of the cover and whose target is the nerve of H.

Comment: There is a paper ``Equivariant bundles with Abelian structural group''
by Lashof, Segal, and myself (http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/PAPERS/44.pdf) that might be relevant. It shows that for any compact Lie group G and abelian compact Lie group A, the G-space Map(EG,BA) is a classifying G-space for principal G-bundles with structure group A.  No Cech cohomology, but the last page shows the relevance of Segal's topological cohomology, defined in his paper ``Cohomology of topological groups''.   